# List of attacks on Tor

Tags: attacks

I'm studying Tor for educational purposes and I haven't been able to find many resources about attacks on Tor (even the once that have been patched). Most of the articles are too general or don't explain the attack in detail. I've even found this [Thirteen years of Tor attacks](https://github.com/Attacks-on-Tor/Attacks-on-Tor), but it's almost unreadable. Can you share some of the links of the attacks that you think are interesting? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think anyone will do your research for you but here are some links with a lot of good information.

- [Paul Syverson](http://www.syverson.org/)'s home page
- [Roger Dingledine](https://www.freehaven.net/~arma/cv.html)'s home page
- [2012 Tor Specification](https://people.torproject.org/~karsten/tor-design-2012-11-14.pdf)
- [Selected Papers in Anonymity](https://www.freehaven.net/anonbib/topic.html)

Comment: thank you, I really appreciate your help! I was just hoping that users with more experience might know some sites that aren't listed as the first ones on google. Tor is a very popular topic among a wide variety of people, so it's fairly hard for me to find something that really explains how the protocol works and not just general info.